# R or MATLAB - how to fit a function to experimental data, satisfying specific constraints

Tags: r, regression, matlab

My first question here, hope it works :) I have experimental data $(x_i,y_i),i=1\ldots n$, $n=O(10)$, which describe a function $y=f(x)+\epsilon$ defined in $I=[0,1]$. $y_i$ is a ratio between measured positive quantities: $y_i=z_i/w_i$, where $0 < z_i \leq w_i \forall i$. For these reasons, $f$ satisfies the following constraints:

1. $f(0)=1$
2. $f(1)=1$
3. $ 0 < f(x) \leq 1 \forall x \in I $

EDIT1: Experimental data should satisfy constraints, but in a few cases $y_i$ > 1 (by 3% in one case, and by much less in few other cases). That's weird because I was told this couldn't happen, because of the way measures are taken...I could follow this up with the data reduction team, but I don't think it makes a huge difference.

The true $f$ should look like this:

[image]

I would like to fit my data with a model which ideally satisfies the constraints. The goal is to make predictions for values of $x \in I$ (it doesn't make any physical sense to consider values $x<0$ or $x>1$).

I started with a least squares polynomial regression. Of course, that doesn't satisfy the constraints, in particular constraint 3, which makes using the curve to make predictions quite risky. I thought of 3 possible strategies:

1. fit a model such as $1-x(1-x)g(x)+\epsilon$. For $g(x)$ is continuous in $I$, this model satisfy constraints 1 and 2: I have no idea how to satisfy constraint 3, though, and also I have no idea which model to assume for $g(x)$.
2. as $y_i$= $y_i=z_i/w_i$, with $0 < z_i \leq w_i \forall i$, it may make sense to fit a rational function to my data, i.e., assume model
   $y=\frac{1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_ix^i}{1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^m \beta_i(1-x)^i} + \epsilon $ which satisfies constraints 1 and 2. Again, no idea how to satisfy constraint 3, which values to use for $n$ and $m$, etc. (very low, of course, as I have very few experimental data.).
3. a variation on strategy 2 may be to fit two separate functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ respectively to $(x_i,z_i)$ and $(x_i,w_i)$, and then just compute the ratio. Maybe each function is better behaved, and polynomial regression may be sufficient.

What do you suggest me to do? Do you have any better ideas? Thanks!

EDIT2: I provide a picture of one of my fits (here the model is a second degree polynomial). I cannot show the $y=0$ line in the picture. The bounds are 95% pointwise prediction bounds for the fit.

[image]

EDIT3: The first drawing is taken from a book. Similar drawings are shown in other books. They are based partly on theory (the behavior for $x \to 0$ and $x \to 1$), and partly on experimental data which the books don't report. I don't have access to the original papers. My data sets can be considered in broad agreement. Some are closer than others, but since my case is not exactly the same than that reported in books, I believe the agreement is fair. However, my fit doesn't look at all like the "expected" $f(x)$, and that's my problem.

As I stated already, the goal of the fit is to make predictions of $f(x)$ for  $0<x<1$.

Comment: When you write $n = O(10)$, how does that relate to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation? COuld you just state plainly typical sample sizes as they affect what is practical here?

Comment: What's the noise like? does it become almost zero near x=0 and x=1 and bigger where the y-value is further from 1? Or is it essentially zero everywhere?

Comment: @Glen_b, it's not easy to say. I just got the measured values without the error bands. There are no measurements very close to $x$=0 and $x$=1. Tipically the best we get are about. $x$=.1 and $x$=.9 . By looking at the error bands for some related quantities, I'd guess that $w_i$ has a constant, small error, while $z_i$  has an error which more or less linearly increase from x=0.1 to x= 0.7-0.9. However, if you need something more accurate, I'd have to dig deeper with the people who postprocessed test results.

Comment: I was actually asking about variation of points away from the curve rather than error bands on individual points.

Comment: @Glen_b, if I understand correctly, you want to see the fitted curve and the original data. Ok, I'll add another image to my post. I'll have to remove the scale from it before, so that may take a few minutes.

Comment: Well, I didn't actually ask to see your data, but if you can show it, that will give the information I did ask for.

Comment: @Glen_b :) thanks, but if I remove scales, that shouldn't be a problem. The issue now is that there seems to be something wrong with my fit...I'll have to double check data before I can post a meaningful image, that may take some time.

Comment: I have the impression this will become much simpler if you transform your data, do the fit and transform back.  My suggestion would be a logit - this will fulfill condition 3 always.

Comment: @Glen_b, here's the picture, looks like some measures were actually larger than 1 after all. By itself, that wouldn't be a big issue, but actually there are too many points in my data which are very close to $y=1$, and I guess that's driving the polynomial above 1.

Comment: @bdecaf, how does logit satisfy constraint 1? I thought it would go to 0 for $x \to 1$, and to 1 for $x \to 1$. Probably we're not thinking of the same model. Maybe you could elucidate in a answer? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your second drawing doesn't look all that much like your first drawing. Given your data, does the first drawing apply? In the first picture, is there a known functional form; if not, how was that drawing arrived at? What's the purpose of the model? (what are you or others going to use it to do? is it going to be used to discern some feature of the curve, to make predictions, to estimate some quantity, to calibrate something?)

Comment: @Glen_b, that's precisely my problem! There's not enough space to discuss the point in the comments, so I edited my question. See above.

Comment: @DeltaIV basically just use functions that at these points have a limit of infinity. I'm thinking of a model like $y = A + B/x + C/(1-x)+ ...$

Comment: It's not crucial, but do you know the names/authors/journal/year of any of the papers? It might give a bit more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try an answer I suggest you use following ansatz:

1. $v = A+ B/x + C/(1-x) +... $ (add terms to your liking)
2. Since you have measured values > 1 transform to the original scale: $y_{est} = \frac{e^v}{1+e^v}$
3. minimize $|y_{meas}-y_{est}|^2$ to find the parameters - both R and Matlab are *very* good in this.

You will see the steps 1. and 2. take care of all your constraints and you are free to add additional terms to your liking - as long as they produce real valued results.